# How to write generic code the Rails way for superclass object in Rails partial view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

## Problem

My app manages `ProjElements`, which are subclassed into:

- `Milestone`
- `Task`
- `Decision`
- ... etc

For a given `ProjElement`'s `show.html.erb`, you can comment on that project element instance (e.g. you can add a comment on `Milestone XYZ` or `Decision ABC`). Like this:

```
// display project element specific stuff
//  - e.g. show.html.erb for Milestone has milestone-specific stuff
//  - e.g. show.html.erb for Decision has decision-specific stuff

// provide comment functionality
//  - e.g. for Milestone's show.html.erb, code looks like

    <%= form_for [@milestone, Comment.new] do |f| %>
      <% if @milestone.comments.size > 0 %>
         ...
      <% end %>
      <% f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

## Proposed approach

- I plan to use a partial for the comment code and use it across the various `show.html.erb` views for different project elements, as per DRY. But ...
- **How do I write generic code for the partial, the Rails way, so that the partial can deal with different project elements?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the element's subclass instance through the locals hash. In app/views/milestones/show.html.erb

```
render :partial => 'shared/comments', :locals => { :element => @milestone }
```

In app/views/shared/_comments.html.erb

```
<% form_for [element, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```